# Gradle jar task: what is includes path pattern relative to?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, filter

I have the following code tree in a gradle subproject called dap4:

```
dap4
 - src
   - main
     - java
       - dap4
         - core
         - shared
         - servlet
         -...
```

I want to build a jar file from a subset of the code in this tree. I am using this gradle:

```
jar {
  includes '<prefix>/core'
  includes '<prefix>/servlet'
}
```

My question is: what is the proper value for `<prefix>`:

- dap4
- src/main/java/dap4
- something else
- Should it start with '/' or not?

In other words, to what is the includes path filter relative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`includes` references the relative file.  If your build.gradle file is located at the *topmost* `dap4` level, then the appropriate path would be `src/main/java/dap4`.  If the build.gradle file is located in the *innermost* `dap4` folder, then omitting the prefix is fine - just navigate to the folder you want (example:  `core/`).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have started with src/, so in your case-

```
    includes 'src/main/java/dap4'
```